# Android 10+ pdf doesnt send to Gmail

Tags: android, gmail, android-11

I have files on my phone. I cant send pdf files to Gmail, for a test a created a list with png and pdf files, this files is located in the same folder. But, png files is sended to Gmail, pdf files didnt attachet. Cant understand why its happens

My code:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);

     

            String theme = "Test";

            emailIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            emailIntent.setType(" message/rfc822"); 

            String to[] = {sendTo};
            emailIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_EMAIL, to);

            emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
            emailIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_SUBJECT, theme);

           emailIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_TEXT, context.getResources().getString(R.string.text_email_message_body));
try {
            ((Activity) context).startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Choose an Email client:"));
        }catch (Exception e){
        }
```

**UPD:**

this code is works on android 9 and 8

**UPD:**

i have added files like this:

```
       ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<>();

 File fileIn1 = new File("/storage/emulated/0/TestApp/TestFolder/201123192703_1.png");
        Uri u1 = Uri.fromFile(fileIn1);

        File fileIn = new File("/storage/emulated/0/TestApp/TestFolder/201124171209_1.pdf");
        Uri u = Uri.fromFile(fileIn);

        File fileIn2 = new File("/storage/emulated/0/TestApp/TestFolder/201124171209_2.pdf");
        Uri u2 = Uri.fromFile(fileIn2);

        File fileIn3 = new File("/storage/emulated/0/TestApp/TestFolder/test.pdf");
        Uri u3 = Uri.fromFile(fileIn3);

        uris.add(u);
        uris.add(u2);
        uris.add(u1);
        uris.add(u3);
```

Comment: Presumably, there is some issue with `uris` and the `Uri` values that it contains.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for a comment, i have added a code, how i add a files to `uris`

Comment: @CommonsWare only png attached to gmail

Comment: You should be crashing with a `FileUriExposedException` on Android 7.0+. Please use `FileProvider` and `getUriForFile()` to create `Uri` values for your files.

Comment: @CommonsWare why png file URI works without `FileProvider` ?

Comment: I have been wondering that myself. :-)

Comment: @CommonsWare i have written code like you sad. And everything is work well) thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file:` `Uri` values have been banned since Android 7.0, with an eye towards the sorts of "scoped storage" restrictions that you see in Android 10+. Generally, you will crash with a  `FileUriExposedException` when you try using a `file:` `Uri` in an `Intent` — I am not certain why you are not crashing here. On the whole, when putting a `Uri` in an `Intent`, it needs to use a `content:` scheme, and the typical way to get one of those for a file is via `FileProvider` and `getUriForFile()`.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `emailIntent.setType(" message/rfc822");`  with
`emailIntent.setType("application/pdf")`

Comment: thanks for an answer, tryied to do like you sad, `emailIntent.setType("application/pdf")` but i have the same result. Only png file was attached